# JQuery not detecting partials views in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, jquery-autocomplete

I`m trying to add autocomplete to a field that is included in a partial view in a Rails 3 app.

I can`t tell JQuery to look for it via form name, since a random attribute is generated every time the field is rendered.

Here's rundown of the code:

cardio_exercises.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
    $('input.Cardio').autocomplete
      source: ['Elliptical trainer','Stair stepper (Stairmaster)','Stationary or recumbent bike','Jacob`s ladder','Arm ergometer (arm cycle)','Rowing machine','Treadmill walking','Treadmill running','Kettlebells','Interval training','Box jumps','Step ups','Plyometrics','Cycling','Jogging','Running','Power walking','Swimming','Water jogging/running','Bleacher running','Spinning','Step aerobics','Walking the dog','Playing with your dog','Taking the stairs','Jumping jacks']
```

In the partial I added a class of Cardio to the input field:

_cardio_exercise_fields.html.erb

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Exercise Name</b><br>
    <%= f.text_field :exercise_name, :class => 'Cardio' %></td>
  <td>
    <b>Duration</b><br>
    <%= f.text_field :duration %> minutes   
  </td>
</table>
```

I have no clue about JS/jQuery so I would appriaciate any advice on the matter.

I know that it works (autocomplete) in normal views, just not in the partial in trying to implement it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery works normally in Rails3, I mean, once the page is rendered,

```
$('input.Cardio')   // =>  will get a result:   [input.Cardio]
```

I suggest you install the firebug and watch the error message from its console. 
( or developer tool in chrome & safari)

Comment: I did, nothing comes up. I`ve also tried $('[id*=exercise_name]') & gives me nothing.

Comment: so what is the result of `$('input.Cardio')` in your machine?